# Line integrals; How to set $t$ boundary?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm having a hard time understanding how to set t boundaries in line integrals...

The question is: find the line integral of $f(x,y,z)$ over the straight line segment from $(1,2,3)$ to $(0,-1,1)$. I figured out that  $\bar{r}(t)=(1-t) \hat{i}  + (2-3t) \hat{j} +(3-2t) \hat{k}  $, and  $| v | = \sqrt{14} $.

But I don't know how I should set up boundaries for t. My textbook says  $0\leq t \leq 1$, but why??? How do I calculate this??? I thank in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boundaries should be 0 and 1 since those values of $t$ correspond to the correct coordinates for your given begin- and endpoints.

Comment: Thank you so much! Can I ask just one more question? I think I almost get this now. If  $\int_{c} x ds$, where C is the parabolic curve $x=t$ and $y=t^2$ from (0,0) to (2,4), then would t be $0\leq t \leq 2$ or $-2\leq t\leq 2$?

Comment: @user125342 try to plug in those values in the equations defining $x$ and $y$. You will see what your answer is.

Answer (score 1):

To say what Danu said in other words: $r(0)=(1,2,3); r(1)=(0,1,-1)$,